# When did dead animals (mayta) become prohibited (haram) for muslims?

Tags: quran, revelation, order-of-revelation

I have gone through the verses in the Quran where dead animals (mayta) is mentioned to be prohibited for a Muslim to eat *(except situations where it really is necessary)*. What I can recall for now is that I've read the verses:  2:173, 5:3, 6:145 , 16:115

**Is it possible to draw a conclusion of when (mayta) first was prohibited in the Quran?**
If possible, which verse would that be? In my (small) analyze I've done, I would guess it was in 16:115 or 2:173 (maybe in surat Ana'am too), but God knows best.
Also I don't neglect the logical possibility that it was prohibited before it even was revealed in the Quran.

**Are there records of hadiths where it says that dead animals (mayta) is prohibited to eat, before the prohibition was revealed in the Quran?**
*If records like that doesn't exist, it wouldn't mean it never was prohibited before, because truly we don't have all "hadiths" ever existed, so we can't know for sure.*

Comment: I don't know about Islamic references, but "[Do not eat anything you find already dead](http://biblehub.com/deuteronomy/14-21.htm)" is one of the dietary restrictions from the Bible which would've been known to the Jews of the time.

Comment: @goldPseudo Thanks. I am aware of that, i was more looking for the first "real" prohibition in islam regarding it. Truly, it might have been agreed to have been prohibited without a real prohibition in the Quran, because it already existed in the previous abrahamic religions, therefore it might not have been mentioned for real until a later period. This is a possibility i accept.

Comment: @Kilise AFAIK mayta was prohibited already for former nations among ahl-al-Kitab.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Yes, I am aware of that too. But the verse (and others) "وَمَا لَكُمْ أَلَّا تَأْكُلُوا مِمَّا ذُكِرَ اسْمُ اللَّهِ عَلَيْهِ وَقَدْ فَصَّلَ لَكُم مَّا حَرَّمَ عَلَيْكُمْ" "wa qad fassala lakom", i.e in my understanding they must have been informed  (while being muslims) some how about what is forbidden and what is not forbidden to eat. So again, in my understanding, the prohobition must have been a direct information from the prophet (saw) or from a verse. That is why I ask when it first got prohibited for muslims.

Comment: Well, i think question is wrong. Because anything which was known to be good or bad by jews or christians(in this case both), it was automatically as is in islam, if anything was needed to be changed it was mentioned.
 If you are asking about first proper mention of not eating dead in islamic scriptures than its different, but asking when it first got PROHIBITED is different.

Comment: Moreover, even if the question is about first proper mention of not eating dead animal, even than i would not spent much time finding this if i already don't know, because(in my view) i think this will be waste of time, with no visible gain for us. We know its prohibited, so it is, it is mentioned we all know, so it is... it is interesting why this question is being asked, would love to know :)

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal thats why i wrote "I don't neglect the logical possibility that it was prohibited before it even was reveled in the Quran." I am looking for the first  proper mention of it being haram in the quran or hadith .  If it wasn't mentioned at all in the Quran or hadtih do you mean that it still would be haram to eat mayta?

Comment: @Kilise don't get me wrong, (i might had sounded rude) but i am actually curious why this question is being asked.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal - " Because anything which was known to be good or bad by jews or christians(in this case both), it was automatically as is in islam" - Do you really think that all converts knew about all the laws in the previous scriptures? They had to be told about certain rules when they converted, this verse also verifies that "وَقَدْ فَصَّلَ لَكُم مَّا حَرَّمَ عَلَيْكُمْ" - Secondly, it's not relevant why I am asking the question. Maybe just of curiosity, or maybe I am doing a research about halal meat? To say it's a waste of time is in my opinion not good.

Comment: I just asked because the reason might benefit us too, anyway. So, yes, not every convert or christian or jew has to know everything about christianity or judaism, but things of this importance, halal and haram is the fundamental things which every believer know and even 10 year olds would know what they eat what they don't. At-least basics, so in this specific case, i would expect them to know about this.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal The reason I ask would be off topic and irrelevant. "even 10 year olds would know what they eat what they don't" - If you give halal meat and regular (non-halal) meat to a 10 year old, do you really think he will know the difference? These rules are taught, not self learned. The rules of islam was built slowly, alcohol wasn't prohibited day one. Similarly that might have been true for meat.

Comment: If you give this kind of meat to even me i would not recognize :) the point here is knowing what kind is halal and what is not halal. recognizing mere meat is completely different. And about alcohol, it was not considered prohibited by jews and christians at the tim. so its different too

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal You are missing the whole point here. Lets stop this off topic discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add some of my further research which aims to answer the question: *"Is it possible to draw a conclusion of when (mayta) first was prohibited in the Quran?"*.

As @Seeker said in his answer, I came to the conclusion that the first prohibition in the Quran of dead meat (mayta) was in either of the verses:

- Al-An'aam (6:145)
- An-Nahl (16:115)

In my research I found out that it seems that Surat An-Ana'am was revealed in the end of the Meccan period, probably the last year before the Hijra while Surat An-Nahl says to be revealed some months before the Hijra. This should then give that al-An'aam was revealed before. See "Muhammad Asad The Message of the Quran":

> WITH the possible exception of two or three verses, the whole of this surah was revealed in one
>   piece, towards the close of the Mecca period - almost certainly in the last year before the
>   Prophet's exodus to Medina.
>
> Muhammad Asad The Message of the Quran, Al-An'am (Cattle)
>
> ACCORDING to almost all the authorities (including the Itqan), this Surah was revealed a few
>   months before the Prophet's emigration to Medina. Although some commentators maintain that
>   the last three verses belong to the Medina period, there is no evidence for this more or less
>   speculative view.
>
> Muhammad Asad The Message of the Quran, An-Nahl (The Bee)

The verse in Surat al-Ana'am helps us to understand that it was revealed before An-Nahl:

> وَعَلَى الَّذِينَ هَادُوا حَرَّمْنَا كُلَّ ذِي ظُفُرٍ ۖ وَمِنَ الْبَقَرِ وَالْغَنَمِ حَرَّمْنَا عَلَيْهِمْ شُحُومَهُمَا إِلَّا مَا حَمَلَتْ ظُهُورُهُمَا أَوِ الْحَوَايَا أَوْ مَا اخْتَلَطَ بِعَظْمٍ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ جَزَيْنَاهُم بِبَغْيِهِمْ ۖ وَإِنَّا لَصَادِقُونَ
>
> And to those who are Jews We prohibited every animal of uncloven hoof; and of the cattle and the sheep We prohibited to them their fat, except what adheres to their backs or the entrails or what is joined with bone. [By] that We repaid them for their injustice. And indeed, We are truthful.
>
> [Surat Al-Ana'am, verse 146](https://quran.com/6/146)

We notice that this is one verse after the mentioned 6:145.

While in Surat An-Nahl it says:

> وَعَلَى الَّذِينَ هَادُوا حَرَّمْنَا مَا قَصَصْنَا عَلَيْكَ مِن قَبْلُ ۖ وَمَا ظَلَمْنَاهُمْ وَلَٰكِن كَانُوا أَنفُسَهُمْ يَظْلِمُونَ
>
> And to those who are Jews We have prohibited that **which We related to you before**. And We did not wrong them [thereby], but they were wronging themselves.

The key here is "which We related to you before", i.e at least in Surat Al-An'aam.

### Conclusion

The first verse in the Quran which talks about mayta being prohibited should be in **Surat Al-An'aam verse 145**, this according to above comments.

This said, I still do not know when exactly mayta (dead meat) was prohibited the first time, because in the same Surat, some verses earlier it is said that the Muslims already has got a good explanation of what was forbidden to eat and what not:

> وَمَا لَكُمْ أَلَّا تَأْكُلُوا مِمَّا ذُكِرَ اسْمُ اللَّهِ عَلَيْهِ وَقَدْ فَصَّلَ لَكُم مَّا حَرَّمَ عَلَيْكُمْ إِلَّا مَا اضْطُرِرْتُمْ إِلَيْهِ
>
> And why should you not eat of that upon which the name of Allah has been mentioned **while He has explained in detail to you what He has forbidden you**, excepting that to which you are compelled
>
> [Surat Al-Ana'am, verse 119](https://quran.com/6/119)

This would then indicate that the Prophet (saw) had instructed the believers *(by wahy which wasn't revelead in the Quran)* of what to eat (and not to eat) before any verse was revealed.

Answer (score 2):

The prohibition on eating dead animal meat is referenced to four surah's in Quran, which you also mentioned in the Question. They are

1. Al Baqarah (2:173)
2. Al Maidah (5:4)
3. Al An'aam (6:145)
4. Al Nahl (16 :115)

[can be confirmed here](http://miraculousquran.blogspot.com/2009/08/surah-al-baqarah-2173-wisdom-behind.html)

Now the question should be, which surah was descended first. As you can see [here](http://learnqurankareem.blogspot.com/2013/04/list-of-all-surah.html),

The list shows only **Surah Al-An'aam** and **Al-Nahl** were descended in Makkah. Now we have to find out, which surah descended first between these two?

You can see [here,](https://www.missionislam.com/quran/revealationorder.htm) In the revelation order, that surah Al-An'aam was descended first in Makkah. Now about the time and the Prophet location, It can be seen [here,](http://www.qurantutoring.com/quran/Tafhim_al_Quran/Quran/6/index.html) The whole situation of Prophet is defined.

The finding of exact date and time for the descendance of this Surah is little vague, but It could be found with the clue, that is provided [here,](http://www.qurantutoring.com/quran/Tafhim_al_Quran/Quran/6/index.html), that Prophet was going on a she-camel when this Surah was descended. If researched more finely, that on which day and time, Prophet was going where, The exact time and date of Prohibition of Dead Animal meat could be find out.

That will require more digging, I will update my answer, as soon as I find it. Hope it Helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it's answering my question because I asked about **when** mayta (dead animals) was first prohibited in the quran or through the prophet (reference to a hadith), **not how** things get prohibited in general.

Comment: I hope, this is what you asked.

Comment: Thanks, it starts to look more like I asked for. It seems that Surat Anaam was reveled in the end of the meccan period, probably the last year before the hijra and that Surat Nahl says to be reveled some months before the hijra.... if this information is correct, then surat anaam would be the first prohibitions in the quran, but if you analyze the verses talking about that mayta is haram in surat anaam you will notice that it ALREADY was prohibited before this sura, so maybe by the prophet (in a hadith) prohibited it before this verse.

Comment: That is also why in my question i added this: *"Are there records of hadiths where it says that dead animals (mayta) is prohibited to eat, before the prohibition was reveled in the Quran?
If records like that doesn't exist, it wouldn't mean it never was prohibited before, because truly we don't have all "hadiths" ever existed, so we can't know for sure."*

Comment: I am giving you the bounty, because time is soon up, but hopefully you will add some more information of what is mentioned in the comments here.

Comment: Sure, as soon as i find it.

Comment: Did you do any further research?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't find any specific details related until now