# Why is Music considered forbidden in Islam when it is not in the previous revelations given to the Jews and Christians?

Tags: halal-haram, christianity, malaikah, music, judaism

All of the holy books that came before the Qur'an are clear that the malaikah (angels) sing, the most beautiful music such as cannot even be imagined by the human ear. These verses have been confirmed by people who have died and come back to report malaikah singing and it's purity and clarity.

Also it is well known that King David played the harp, and King Solomon composed the Song of Songs. Also in other holy books, it says that Allah specifically commanded the Jews that they are to make music in

> [2 Chronicles 29:25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Chronicles%2029%3A25) *And he set the Levites in the house of the
>   LORD with cymbals, with psalteries, and with harps, according to the
>   commandment of David, and of Gad the king's seer, and Nathan the
>   prophet: for so was the commandment of the LORD by his prophets.*

The Question is: **Why is Music considered forbidden in Islam when it is not in the previous revelations given to the Jews and Christians?**

Comment: Muslims believe that the previous books have been corrupted by the people and evidence from them is not admitted in jurisprudence. You might as well ask why Muslims don't believe in the divinity of Christ when its clear in the gospels. Additionally Muslims believe in the divine origin of the Torah and Injeel and have no evidence for the divine origin of the other works of the Tanakh like the book of Chronicles. Finally there is a difference between singing and musical instruments ... singing is acceptable whereas musical instruments other than the daff(hand drum) are not.

Comment: @Uma In my question "[When did dead animals (mayta) become phohibited (haram) for muslims?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37604/15201)" many comments state that mayta already was prohibited for the people of the book (ahlu al-kitab), and therefore automatically was prohibited for muslims without any revelation in the Quran. If the comments are correct, they would seem to contradict your saying that evidence from them is not admitted.

Comment: @Kilise There are a lot of prohibitions on food in Judaism which aren't present in Islam, for example camel meat and mixing milk with meat are forbidden in Judaism but not in Islam. Scholars do give reference to previous revelations as complementary information when it agrees with Islamic principles, but the Torah and Injeel are not used to establish Islamic law unless there is proof to that effect in the Quran and Hadith.

Comment: @Uma Yes I am aware of some of the differences in the prohibition of food, but that isn't relevant to the comment because it was addressing mayta. Anyway this will become off topic if we continue discuss it. I think a good question could be arrived from this though, maybe i'll post it later in sha Allah.